# Can SSIS transfer data from a SQL Server 2005 database to a 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to transfer data on a regular automated basis from a database running on a SQL Server 2005 instance to a remote database running on a SQL Server 2008 instance. I'm new to database administration and using SSIS.

Is it possible to configure an SSIS package to transfer data between two SQL databases of different versions? The package would need to be configured and installed on the SQL 2005 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer data between 2005 and 2008.

The big gotcha you need to look out for is that the SSIS packages themselves can't be moved between the two.  If you create the package in 2005, it needs to run in 2005.  You can convert the package to 2008, but then it needs to run in 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You could forget about SSIS and create a linked server and use stored procedures in a job step instead.  SSIS can be overkill and time consuming for most SQL to SQL transfers.